# NoReverseMatch when href name in urls

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I get NoReverseMatch when using

```
{% url 'detail' a.id %}
```

in my template.

I have not included $ in my urls. Found that on a google search.

This is my main urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^item/', include('item.urls')),
    url(r'^status/', include('status.urls')),
]
```

and my status.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    # /status/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # /status/<status_id>/
    url(r'^(?P<status_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

It work if I remove `{% url 'detail' a.id %}`and hardcode `status/{{ a.id }}`

I don't understand where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need a keyword argument. Try this:

```
{% url 'detail' status_id=a.id %}
```

The reason is that your `detail` view receives a keyword argument according to your `urls.py`: `(?P<status_id>[0-9]+)`

Comment: Nope. But I found it now. typical after hours of searching with no luck. After writing a question you find it after 15min.
So I needed to set:  app_name = 'status'   in the urls. and then write {% url 'status:detail' a.id %}  This made it work.

Comment: @sumpen You can pass keyword arguments or positional arguments to the `url` tag.